# SSL connection on Blackberry Playbook development

Tags: ssl, https, blackberry-playbook

is it possible to setup an ssl connection on playbook? I found SecureSocket class in the api but it seems playbook platform doesnt support ssl connections. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're trying to connect to, but if it's a web server, then you can use URLRequest to connect via https, which uses an SSL connection.

I don't think there's currently a general way to do it in AIR, without using a third-party library, however.